# Adding ":" time-formatting using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

For an input file named Lab1:

```
034023  052030
034023  022130
044023  012030
034223  022030
034123  152030
024023  152030
```

AWK command
`awk 'gsub(/[0-9][0-9]/,"&:",$1) gsub(/[0-9][0-9]/,"&:",$2)' Lab1`

results in:

```
03:40:23: 05:20:30:
03:40:23: 02:21:30:
04:40:23: 01:20:30:
03:42:23: 02:20:30:
03:41:23: 15:20:30:
02:40:23: 15:20:30:
```

How can I prevent the trailing colons?

**desired result**

```
    03:40:23 05:20:30
    03:40:23 02:21:30
```

Comment: `sed -r 's/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\>/:\1:\2/g'`

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Could you include the desired result?

Comment: I want to use awk @Costas

Comment: @joepd see update

Comment: Even shorter `sed -r 's/[0-9]{2}\B/&:/g'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '
    {
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
            sub(/[0-9]{4}$/,":&",$i)
            sub(/:[0-9]{2}/,"&:",$i)
        }
     }
     1
     ' <<<\
'034023  052030
034023  022130
044023  012030
034223  022030
034123  152030
024023  152030'
```

produces:

```
03:40:23 05:20:30
03:40:23 02:21:30
04:40:23 01:20:30
03:42:23 02:20:30
03:41:23 15:20:30
02:40:23 15:20:30
```

Other scripts are
1.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
gsub(/[0-9]{4}\>/,":&") &&
gsub(/:[0-9][0-9]/,"&:")
```

2.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
gsub(/[0-9]{2}\B/,"&:")
```

3.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
    FS=OFS=""
}
/[0-9]{6}  [0-9]{6}/{
    $3=":"$3
    $4=$4":"
    $11=":"$11
    $12=$12":"
    print
}
```

4.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
/[0-9]{6}  [0-9]{6}/{
    printf("%02d:%d:%s:%d:%d\n",
        substr($0,0,2),
        substr($0,3,2),
        substr($0,5,6),
        substr($0,11,2),
        substr($0,13,2))
}
```

Comment: You are awesome.+1

Comment: +1 excellent work but I'm confused on `4` in code `substr($0,5,6)` it brings results as `23  05` why?

Comment: @asadz I do not understand the question. What do you mean "why"? We need not change the end of 1st word so as beginning of second ones so it's output unchanged.

Comment: @Costas sorry for confusion I want to know why `substr($0,5,6)` when run separately matches `23 05` it should only match `23`.Can you please explain?

Comment: @asadz It shouldn't match `23` because `substr(s, i, n)` returns the *substring of string **s**, starting at index **i**, of length **n***

Comment: @Costas i tested the code `substr($0,5,6)` for e.g `024023  152030` with length **n** to be `6` it should never go as far and match `space` and `15`?

Comment: @asadz there are 2 spaces between `23` and `15` (for `024023 152030` so it starts from 5th symbol `2` and than `3` `space` `space` `1` `5` == totally 6 symbols)

Answer (score 1):

Best way I got for now but this is not only way

```
[root@virt03 test]# awk 'gsub(/[0-9][0-9]/,":&",$1) gsub(/[0-9][0-9]/,":&",$2)' lab1 | sed 's/://1' | sed 's/://3'
03:40:23 05:20:30
03:40:23 02:21:30
04:40:23 01:20:30
03:42:23 02:20:30
03:41:23 15:20:30
02:40:23 15:20:30
[root@virt03 test]# cat lab1
034023  052030
034023  022130
044023  012030
034223  022030
034123  152030
024023  152030
[root@virt03 test]#
```

Comment: +1 `s/://1` over here `1` matches the first occurrence?

Comment: @asadz Yes I am applying it only on 1st occurrence and 4th occurrence which is eventually 3rd occurrence after 1st occurrence changes with sed.